# Cascading save Entity objects with Foreign Key as a part of composite Primary Key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I would like to persist object of my `QuestionCompletion` class with all child elements. One of these childs has a composite primary key. And as a part of this primary key I have also foreign key to another entity. As a result I am getting this error:

```
Exception caught during request processing: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException:
could not set a field value by reflection setter of com.example.model.domain.QuestionCompletionAnswerPK.questionCompletionId
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: could not set a field value by reflection
setter of com.example.model.domain.QuestionCompletionAnswerPK.questionCompletionId
```

And the last "caused by" is of course `NullPointerException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is part of my code. The last line causes error.

```
QuestionCompletion questionCompletion = new QuestionCompletion();
List<QuestionCompletionAnswer> answers = new ArrayList<QuestionCompletionAnswer>();
for (;;) { // loop isn't important; it's loop for answers
    ExtendedQuestion extendedQuestion = new ExtendedQuestion();
    extendedQuestion.setId(extendedQuestionId); //extendedQuestionId is known to me in that place
    for (;;) { // loop isn't important; it's loop for question answers
        //questionCompletion and extendedQuestion are popualted here
        QuestionCompletionAnswer questionCompletionAnswer = new QuestionCompletionAnswer();
        questionCompletionAnswer.setQuestionCompletion(questionCompletion); 
        questionCompletionAnswer.setExtendedQuestion(extendedQuestion); 
        answers.add(questionCompletionAnswer);
    }
}
questionCompletion.setAnswers(answers);
questionCompletionService.saveOrMerge(questionCompletion);
```

This is my basic entity class I would like to persist with all its childs elements. I have realized that `List<QuestionCompletionAnswer>` causes problems. I have used `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to allow to persist childs elements also.

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
@Table(name = "question_completion")
public class QuestionCompletion implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "question_completion_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "question_completion_gen", sequenceName = "question_completion_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "question_completion_id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "extended_question_id")
    protected List<QuestionCompletionAnswer> answers;
}
```

This is my class - Primary Key for the `QuestionCompletionAnswer` class.

```
@Embeddable
public class QuestionCompletionAnswerPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "question_completion_id")
    protected Long questionCompletionId;

    @Column(name = "extended_question_id")
    protected Long extendedQuestionId;
}
```

And this is class which uses my `EmbeddedId`. Attribues `questionCompletionId` and `questionCompletionId` are the foreign key for some another entities so I have placed below also whole objects of these entities with `@MapsId` annotation.

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
@Table(name = "extended_question_answer")
public class QuestionCompletionAnswer implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private QuestionCompletionAnswerPK id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId(value = "questionCompletionId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_completion_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected QuestionCompletion questionCompletion;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId(value = "extendedQuestionId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "extended_question_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected ExtendedQuestion extendedQuestion;
}
```

Could you tell me if my annotations are correct? Maybe I have mixed up few approaches. Or I can't in that case persist my basic object with all of its child elements.

**EDIT**

Now my mapping looks like:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
@Table(name = "question_completion")
public class QuestionCompletion implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "question_completion_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "question_completion_gen", sequenceName = "question_completion_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "question_completion_id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "questionCompletion")
    protected List<QuestionCompletionAnswer> answers;
}
```

Code of the `QuestionCompletionAnswerPK` class is the same.

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
@Table(name = "extended_question_answer")
public class QuestionCompletionAnswer implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private QuestionCompletionAnswerPK id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @MapsId(value = "questionCompletionId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_completion_id", nullable = false)
    protected QuestionCompletion questionCompletion;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId(value = "extendedQuestionId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "extended_question_id", nullable = false)
    protected ExtendedQuestion extendedQuestion;
}
```

With that mapping I am still getting the same exception.

**EDIT #2**
However when I have changed `QuestionCompletionAnswer` class in this way:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
@Table(name = "extended_question_answer")
public class QuestionCompletionAnswer implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private QuestionCompletionAnswerPK id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_completion_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected QuestionCompletion questionCompletion;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "extended_question_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected ExtendedQuestion extendedQuestion;
}
```

I am getting that exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated 
for:class com.example.model.domain.QuestionCompletionAnswer
```

Comment: Don't add the @joincolumn to the onetomany mapping.  Mark it as mappedby the extendedQuestion mapping instead.  Also remove the updatable=false insertable=false on the manytoone joincolumn def as the are implied by the mapsid annotation.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your comment. I have changed that lines you have described but I am getting still the same error.

Comment: You should change the code above then to show what you now have since the model above is wrong as is.  Also show the NPE stack to see where it is coming from, and be sure you are persisting/merging the referenced questions so the have their IDs assigned.  You might need to set cascade persist on the questionCompletion mapping

Comment: My error is appearing exactly at the moment of saving `questionCompletion` - `Serializable id = getSession().save(questionCompletion);` so in fact I am not getting the id of this entity.

Comment: @Chris I have updated my question. I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: Can you post the code and mapping of ExtendedQuestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit 1 and 2 are still not right.  You need mapsid specified on the relationship or you must set the field in the embedded id with a value yourself.  And when you use mapsid, you shouldn't have the join column marked insertable=false or jpa can't insert a value for you.  The last problem I see is that the new question is not persisted so it doesn't get an id assigned that the answer can reference - you need to explicitly persist the new question in the for loop or mark the relationship in the answer to it to cascade persist.

Comment: I have implemented changes you have described. But there is still issue with saving `QuestionCompletionAnswer` - the same exception. To me `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` is not working in that case. I am going to save it explicitly. However without list of `QuestionCompletionAnswer` objects, `QuestionCompletion` is saving without any problem.

Comment: The error states an NPE is occuring trying to set a field in QuestionCompletionAnswerPK.  Does your QuestionCompletionAnswer even have a QuestionCompletionAnswerPK assigned to id?  Maybe post the full NPE stack trace if assigning a new QuestionCompletionAnswerPK doesn't when creating a new QuestionCompletionAnswer doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you mixing jpa and hibernate annotations ? jpa annotations alone should be enough.
Try with the following mapping (I removed the class `QuestionCompletionAnswerPK`) :

**QuestionCompletion.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question_completion")
public class QuestionCompletion {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "question_completion_gen", sequenceName = "question_completion_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "question_completion_gen")
    @Column(name = "question_completion_id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "questionCompletion")
    protected List<QuestionCompletionAnswer> answers;
}
```

**QuestionCompletionAnswer.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "extended_question_answer")
public class QuestionCompletionAnswer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_completion_fk")
    private QuestionCompletion questionCompletion;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "extended_question_fk")
    private ExtendedQuestion extendedQuestion;
}
```

With this mapping, I run the following test case and it worked :

```
QuestionCompletion questionCompletion = new QuestionCompletion();
ExtendedQuestion extendedQuestion = new ExtendedQuestion();
QuestionCompletionAnswer answer = new QuestionCompletionAnswer();
answer.setQuestionCompletion(questionCompletion);
answer.setExtendedQuestion(extendedQuestion);
questionCompletion.setAnswers(Collections.singletonList(answer));
...
session.save(extendedQuestion);
session.save(questionCompletion);
```